# How to share memory mapped files between Python and another language?

Tags: python, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

How to use the [memory maps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) in Python to share data between Python and a C process whilst not storing anything on disk.

How do both programs read make sure to read from the same location in memory?
If the data is shared with C, is it best to use ctypes from Python, or parse the python objects in C?

Comment: I completely understand your problem and the difficulty of getting into a topic like this. I'm merely suggesting that SO may not be the correct forum for your exploration.

Comment: There are a number of other stack exchange sites that you may want to start with. I'm not familiar with most of them.

Comment: I understand why you would feel that way, and given that you've apparently done some research on the subject, you're probably right. It's a fairly standard comment to leave for OPs that don't show what they've tried. In most cases it turns out to be just people looking for free code. I am not implying that you fall into that category, so I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible with the `mmap` module. It wraps the file-oriented mmap functions, but not the POSIX SHM APIs. You can call them via ctypes though, check out [`shm_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) which returns a file descriptor for a purely-in-memory SHM segment, which you can then mmap.